# Fitting glass lampshade given standard ceiling pendant

Tags: electrical, lamp, uk

I have a standard British ceiling pendant room light in my hallway.  I also have a glass lampshade (which is roughly a truncated cone in shape).  I'd like to fit the lampshade on the pendant.

The part of the pendant fitting that holds the bulb has two pieces of plastic which screw together, which seem to be designed to sandwich a lampshade between the two pieces, holding the shade up.  However, the screw threads are quite short, and my glass lampshade has a wall thickness which is too thick to allow the inner and outer screw threads to meet -- see sketch (sorry for my bad drawing):

[image]

Looking online I only see complete pendants plus shades (including the shade, the plastic fittings I describe above, the length of pendant wire to the ceiling, and the fitting for the ceiling).  That would require both spending more on a shade I like less, and also unnecessary messing with wiring that's working fine.  I don't see any replacements or adapters for just the part of the fitting that holds the bulb, nor even any full pendant fittings that specify measurements for lampshades they can accept.

The lampshade is small and less than 300 grams (10 oz) in weight.

What's the easiest way to fit the shade?

Comment: Will the shade fit all the way over the hanging part and slide up what you have marked as "Pendant"? Or does it catch and stop? In other words is the diameter of the shade opening large enough to slide up?

Comment: The upper part goes in from the top without catching, and stops when its larger diameter part hits the glass.  The lower half, when inserted from below, is larger than the hole, so it catches and stops.  The hole in the shade and the plastic pendant fitting I drew are exactly the right size to fit, except for the screw thread not being long enough.

Comment: You said "in fact they themselves form a truncated cone shape when screwed together". Can you put the shade on the top and slide it down? I am thinking you can add a large plastic or Lexan washer where the shade is supposed to go so the glass shade has something to catch it and rest on.

Comment: Can I put the shade on the top and slide it down?  No: if I removed the top half of the fitting from the wire to the ceiling to put it in from below, the light bulb would be too low (and it wouldn't sit level).  It's only very slightly tapered; I deleted that part of my comment as I realised it's not actually relevant to the question in your first comment.